# java TestNG calling methods with @Parameters inside @DataProvider

Tags: java, parameters, nullpointerexception, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm trying to get data using **@DataProvider**, which returns `Object[][]`, in which I'm pasting value by calling another method. This method, in its turn, using **@Parameters** to get value from XML.

The problem is that I'm getting `NullPointerException`, because in **@DataProvider** calling required method with **@Parameters** by passing value `null`, hoping that **@Parameters** will change this value to appropriate one from XML.
At the same time, I cannot call method by not passing any arguments to it.

Code:

Class `TestSuite`

```
package blablabla.mainPackage;

import blablabla.framework.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestSuite extends Config {
    FilesOperations fOps = new FilesOperations();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Test(groups = {"positive"},
          dataProvider = "getRandomFileName",
          priority = 1)
    public void createFileRandom(String fileName) throws IOException {
        fOps.createFile(fileName, tempPath);
        fileNames.add(fileName);
    }   
}
```

Class `Config`

```
package blablabla.mainPackage;

import blablabla.framework.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class Config extends DataProviders{
    public static Path tempPath;

    DirectoriesOperations dirOps = new DirectoriesOperations();

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({"path"})
    public void tearUp(String path) throws IOException {
        tempPath = dirOps.createTempDir(Paths.get(path));
    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true, enabled = true)
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        dirOps.deleteTempDirOnExit(tempPath);
    }
}
```

Class `DataProviders`

```
package blablabla.framework;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProviders {
    FilesOperations fOps = new FilesOperations();
    HelpFunctions hf = new HelpFunctions();
    ParametrizedFunctions pf = new ParametrizedFunctions();

    @DataProvider(name = "getRandomFileName")
    public Object[][] getRandomFileName() {
        return new Object[][]{new Object[]{pf.generateRandomFileNameWithExtension(null)}};
    }   
}
```

Class `ParametrizedFunctions`

```
package blablabla.framework;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class ParametrizedFunctions {
    FilesOperations fOps = new FilesOperations();
    HelpFunctions hf = new HelpFunctions();

    @Parameters({"extensionsArray"})
    public String generateRandomFileNameWithExtension(String extensionsArray) {
        return fOps.getFileName(hf.stringToArray(extensionsArray), null);
    }
}
```

Here, `@Parameters({"extensionsArray"})` does't provide a value from XML file. It just takes `null`, that was passed as an argument for calling method `generateRandomFileNameWithExtension()`. And, at the same time, I cannot call this method from **@DataProvider** without passing any argument to method called.

Hope for your suggestions.

Comment: Of course it will. @parameters works when testng calls that method, not when you explicitly call it. If you want to call you have to send the correct value that it can expect. Why dont you take the parameter value at dataprovider level.

Comment: So, it's no any way or workaround to separate DataProviders and code, working with XML parameters?
It is the primary purpose, because methods for working with XML file are highly reusable and usually DataProviders should return combination of multiple values, as from XML, as from other methods, such as string generators.

Comment: I am not really clear with your requirements. But yes you can certainly separate dataproviders from code and it has to be done with your implmenetation. 

Have you tried to use the @paramers on the dataprovider method , and then act on its value ? I think your dataprovider will get access to the parameters in xml and then you can call that method with that value and get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, using @Parameters on the DataProvider level works properly. But the aim is to design framework, that contains independent methods in class PrametraizedFunctions which are completely independent from DataProviders class and then, when creating new test suite, the only thing have to be done is adding few new DataProvier methods, using predefined methods from PrametraizedFunctions class.
But seems like it is impossible by use of TestNG.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Oh, seems I hurried with conclusions. 
Parameters on DataProvider is not working too. 
@DataProvider(name = "getRandomFileName")
 @Parameters({"extensionsArray"})
 public Object[][] getRandomFileName(String extensionsArray) {
  return new Object[][]{new Object[]{pf.generateRandomFileNameWithExtension(extensionsArray)}};

Comment: Failure Exception: org.testng.Exception:           And the description is empty.

Comment: Trying to understand your issue. Instead of trying to get random file extension from, write a static helper function to return a random extension in the dataprovider method itself. for instance,  'Random radomizer = new Random();  ArrayList<String> extensions= new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList(".exe", ".java", ".class")); String randomExtn = extensions.get(randomizer.nextInt(extensions.size()));

Comment: In my testing.xml I have a string <parameter name="extensionsArray" value=".txt, .docx, .png, .doc, .jpg, .pdf"></parameter>, so the range of extensions can be customized according to testing needs. It gives me required flexibility of testSuite customization. So, in this case, I cannot specify any String data in my dataProvider or other methods, because all data is stored in testing.xml or other external files.
The essence in that everyone can change test data by editing xml or other dataStorage files and just simply type 'mvn test' in cmd.

Comment: I dont understand why you didnt get the parameters at dataprovider level. How are you calling the tests .. are you getting the parameters in the @test methods, can you verify once.

Comment: This is my test method: 
@Test(groups = {"positive"},
    dataProvider = "getRandomFileName",
    priority = 1)
 public void createFileRandom(String fileName) throws IOException {
  fOps.createFile(fileName, tempPath);
  fileNames.add(fileName);
 } 

And this is DataProvider: 
@DataProvider(name = "getRandomFileName")
 @Parameters({"extensionsArray"})
 public Object[][] getRandomFileName(String extensionsArray) {
  return new Object[][]{new Object[]{pf.generateRandomFileNameWithExtension(extensionsArray)}};
 }

Comment: Maybe, it happens because the DataProvider method is not static and placed in other class then Test method. But TestSuite class extends Config class, which extends DataProviders class. So, it meens that TestSuite extends DataProviders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The best way to pass parameter from XML into **@DataProvider** is passing `ITestContext context` as the argument to the **@DataProvider** method, and then, get required parameter using:

```
context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("parameterName");
```

Full code of **@DataProvider**:

```
@DataProvider(name = "getRandomFileName")
    public Object[][] getRandomFileName(ITestContext context) {
        String extensionsArray = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("extensionsArray");
        return new Object[][]{new Object[]{pf.generateRandomFileNameWithExtension(extensionsArray)}};
    }
```

Thanks all for your suggestions.